# Rails calling different fields in the same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to call different fields in the same table,

Assignedby != Openedby

I cannot call the user to which the topic is assigned

[mysql users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdnSb.png)

[mysql issues table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFKHw.png)

[show.html.erb screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHTJT.png)

```
<p>
  <strong>Assignedby:</strong>
  <%= @issue.user.try(:fullname) %>

</p>

<p>
  <strong>Openedby:</strong>
 <%= @issue.user.try(:fullname) %>

</p>
```

---

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :project, foreign_key: :project_id, optional: true

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :assignedby_id, optional: true

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :openedby_id, optional: true

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :closedby_id, optional: true

end
```

Comment: you cannot define several relations with the same name (in your case, `user`). You should name them like `belongs_to :user_assigner, foreign_key: :assignedby_id, optional: true, class_name: 'User'`, `belongs_to :user_opener, [...]` etc etc

Comment: @MrYoshiji you are damn fast :)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give all these `belongs_to` associations the same name, they need to be different, for example:

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  with_option optional: true do
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :assigner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :assignedby_id
    belongs_to :creator,  class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :openedby_id
    belongs_to :closer,   class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :closedby_id
  end
end
```

Comment: `assigned_user` is contradictory with the foreign key, it seems the relation here is to point to the user who assigned it, not who is assigned to it